# I cannot respond to comments on my own question (no "add a comment" link anywhere)

Tags: support, comments

I joined a new community and asked a question ([Company's retirement benefit changed while waiting to be eligible, what now?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115169/companys-retirement-benefit-changed-while-waiting-to-be-eligible-what-now#comment359800_115169))

People are commenting & asking questions, but I cannot answer them back. Even "Comment Everywhere" privilege requires 50 reputations and I have 101 reputations.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you perhaps seeing, "Suggest Improvements", instead of, "Add comment"?

Comment: I never thought that would open comment section. thanks

Comment: @Glorfindel you marked the question as a duplicate by referencing to itself.

Comment: My apologies, SE on mobile is sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Workplace is currently [undergoing an experiment](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/experiment-running-a-comment-by-any-other-name) that renames "Add a comment" to "Suggest improvement".  It's an effort to cut down on the amount of commenting and back and forth going on.  So, yes, it's a rename, but if people are asking you questions, it may be better to edit your post to answer their questions than add another comment to the pile.

Comment: I understand the reason for rename. I guess it should still say 'add comment' to question's owner. I can just edit the question instead of suggesting improvement in comments.